# Fetch related rows from tags (slow query)

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using a 2 table tagging system for articles (myisam) and the query to fetch related articles based on the tags and category_id of the article currently being viewed is too slow:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (    
    `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tag` varchar(99) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`,`tag`),
    KEY `tag_ix` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `articles` ( 
    `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `content` text NOT NULL,
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`), 
    KEY `status` (`status`),
    KEY `csd` (`category_id`,`status`,`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query to fetch related articles based on tag and category ID:

```
SELECT 
ta.tag, ta.article_id, ar.article_title
FROM 
tags ta 
INNER JOIN tags tb ON ta.tag = tb.tag AND tb.article_id <> ta.article_id
INNER JOIN articles ar ON tb.article_id = ar.article_id
WHERE
ta.article_id = $currentArticleId AND ar.category_id = $currentCategoryId AND ar.status = 1
```

If I take out the lookup for ar.category_id and ar.status, the query is fast (0.001 as opposed to 0.8 seconds).

Is there any way to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the query plan for the two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I've fixed the issue by adding an index on the articles table for category_id and using an index hint in the query:

```
SELECT 
ta.tag, ta.article_id, ar.article_title
FROM 
tags ta 
INNER JOIN tags tb ON ta.tag = tb.tag AND tb.article_id <> ta.article_id
INNER JOIN articles ar USE INDEX (category_id) ON tb.article_id = ar.article_id
WHERE
ta.article_id = $currentArticleId 
AND ar.category_id = $currentCategoryId 
AND ar.status = 1
```

Now executing in ~0.001 seconds.